# jetpack compose Lottie addAnimataionListener

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, lottie

I want to use Lottie in Jetpack Compose.
here is my code

```
val logoAnimationComposition by rememberLottieComposition(
    spec = LottieCompositionSpec.RawRes(
        resId = R.raw.twitter_logo_motion
    )
)
val logoAnimationProgress by animateLottieCompositionAsState(
    composition = logoAnimationComposition,
    isPlaying = true
)
LottieAnimation(
    modifier = Modifier.size(
        size = logoSize
    ),
    composition = logoAnimationComposition,
    progress = logoAnimationProgress
)
```

I need to know when this animation ends.

i can handle it with the duration of animation that I already know from our ui designer
but it's not a good way.

and the documentation didn't say any thing about it.

what can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of December 11, 2023 the `isAtEnd` property didn't work for me, I had to check the progress float value, when it reaches 1.0, means it finished:

```
val composition by rememberLottieComposition(LottieCompositionSpec.RawRes(animationRes))

val progress by animateLottieCompositionAsState(composition)

LottieAnimation(
    composition = composition,
    contentScale = contentScale,
    progress = { progress },
    modifier = modifier
)

if (progress == 1f) { // animation ended
    LaunchedEffect(Unit) { onAnimationFinished() }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

In Compose we don't use listeners, instead we have to read the state and react to its changes.

You need to remove delegation from `animateLottieCompositionAsState`, then you have access to much more information, for example you can check `isAtEnd`.

Using simple `if` you can display an other view or made some job using [side effects](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/side-effects):

```kotlin
val logoAnimationState = animateLottieCompositionAsState(
    composition = logoAnimationComposition,
    isPlaying = true
)
LottieAnimation(
    modifier = Modifier.size(
        size = logoSize
    ),
    composition = logoAnimationComposition,
    progress = logoAnimationState.progress
)
if (logoAnimationState.isAtEnd) {
    LaunchedEffect(Unit) {
        // to your job
    }
}
```

Comment: `isAtEnd` didn't work for me. So I used progress >= 1.0F instead.